# (Google sheets) Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 6

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Trying to get an Appscript to create PDF form Google Sheet data result which is filled with Google Form.
I create filter page in sheet to exclude used data in created pdf.
After start function if on page I have "zero" cell occurs this exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 6.

```
function createBulkPDF() {

  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1AhTfn-nrV91ewNfdQpRl2L-G2-KNXltoLmYq_YABTF8");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1fM_PcKV59Q9sOSYWRzxA6Ugk65sT-Ktq");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1R-yQz8DtY69EbbwxFTZm0uLFLZ6JUc-z");
  const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("results");
  const currentNewSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("resultsdata");
  const data = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,10).getDisplayValues());

  let errors = [];
  data.forEach(row => {

    try{
      createPDF(row[1],row[0],row[2],row[9],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[0] + " " + row[1],docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder);
      errors.push(["Complete"]);
    } catch(err){
      errors.push(["Failed"]);
    }

});

currentNewSheet.getRange(2, 11,currentNewSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(errors);

}

function createPDF(name,platoon,d,oap,pr,cp,mn,vps,dap,sr,pdfName,docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder) {
  

  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{name}", name);
  body.replaceText("{platoon}", platoon);
  body.replaceText("{d}", d);
  body.replaceText("{oap}", oap);
  body.replaceText("{pr}", pr);
  body.replaceText("{cp}", cp);
  body.replaceText("{mn}", mn);
  body.replaceText("{vps}", vps);
  body.replaceText("{dap}", dap);
  body.replaceText("{sr}", sr);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName);
  tempFile.setTrashed(true)



}
```

Help to add rule to process row only with text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
currentNewSheet.getRange(2, 11,errors.length,errors[0].length).setValues(errors)
```